# Likelihood Ratio Test of Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

I have shown that

$x \log x + (−x) \log( − x) ≥ k$

is a rejection region for the likelihood ratio test for the p parameter of a binomial distribution, where,

$H_0:  = 1/2$
$ 1 :  ≠ 1/2$

Next, I am asked to show that the above rejection region can be simplified in a way that doesn't involve the log function, using the symmetry property of the LHS function.

I have tried plotting the chart, and indeed it is a symmetric function. Have tried rewriting it into a quadratic function, however failed to complete the square.

Comment: Rejection region will put number $X$ of successes, which must be in the sequence $0,1,\dots,n,$ far from $np_0 = n/2.$ For example, if $n=100$ and you want the rejection region for a test near 5% level (without going over 5%). then you want to reject if $X \le 39$ or $X\ge61.$
You need to use probability table of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=0.5),$ normal approx. to binomial, or software. In R, where `dbinom` is binomial PDF, code: `sum(dbinom(c(0:39, 61:100),100,.5))` returns $0.0352002 < 0.05,$ but `sum(dbinom(c(0:40, 60:100),100,.5))` returns
$0.05688793 > 0.05.$

Comment: $x \log x + (n−x) \log(n − x)$ is symmetric about $\frac{n}{2}$ and in fact declining to its minimum and then rising back again.  You can see this from its derivative of $\log\left(\frac{x}{n-x}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Indeed I can show that it is a symmetric function.
However, I'm not sure how to simplify the rejection region into a form that doesn't involve the log function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function

$$g(x)=x\ln x+(n-x)\ln(n-x)\quad,\,x\in (0,n)$$

Differentiating, we have

$$g'(x)=\ln x-\ln(n-x)$$

And $$g''(x)=\frac1x + \frac1{n-x}>0 \quad\forall \,x\in (0,n)\,,$$

so that $g$ is convex in $x$.

Also,

$$
g'(x) 
\begin{cases} >0 &,\text{ if }x>\frac{n}2
\\<0 &,\text{ if }x<\frac{n}2
\\=0 &,\text{ if }x=\frac{n}2
\end{cases}
$$

This gives a fair idea about a picture of $g(x)$ versus $x$. The function decreases for $0<x<\frac{n}2$, reaches a minimum at $x=\frac{n}2$, and then increases for $\frac{n}2<x<n$. In other words, a plot of $g(x)$ should give a U-shaped curve.

In your case, $g(x)$ is defined for $x\in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. But the conclusion above remains same.

Draw a horizontal line that cuts $g(x)$ at two-points $k_1,k_2$ (say) where $k_2>k_1$. This is the $g(x)=k$ line. Now based on the nature of $g(x)$, what can you say about the region $g(x)\ge k $ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I can think of, if we're indeed inside the rejection region, the absolute value of the first derivative would be larger than the absolute value of the first derivative at g(x) = k. Unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Draw the picture.

Comment: I have plotted the graph, I'm still not sure how to proceed.
Would fitting it to some kind of a polynomial function work?

Comment: I can see that $ x <= k_1 $ and $x>=k_2$ would be the rejection region. But not sure how to write $k_1$ and $k_2$ in terms of x in a simple manner.

Comment: It should be clear from the picture that $k_1,k_2$ are such that $g(k_1)=g(k_2)$. Another condition would come from a size restriction for the test.

Comment: You are correct, g(k1) = g(k2) = k essentially. Still not sure how this can simplify the function though. Sorry I'm quite new to this. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nothing more to simplify theoretically. If you have data, then $k_1,k_2$ could be found numerically or exactly using software.